# How can I custom password validator on sylius?

Tags: php, regex, symfony, validation, sylius

I'd like to custom the validators of users' password. I tested this :

http://sylius-try.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bundles/general/overriding_validation.html

http://sylius-older.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization/validation.html

http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/validation.html

However it doesn't work for me.This is my code :

```
#AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml

Sylius\Bundle\UserBundle\Form\Model\ChangePassword:
    properties:
        currentPassword:
            - Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPassword:
                message: sylius.user.plainPassword.wrong_current
                groups: [myGroup]
        newPassword:
            - Regex:
                pattern: ((?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[a-z]).{8,})
                message: myGroup.user.password.regex
                groups: [myGroup]
```

Config :

```
#app/config/config.yml   
 imports:
    - { resource: "@SyliusCoreBundle/Resources/config/app/config.yml" }
```

Services.yml :

```
# app/config/services.yml
parameters:
    sylius.form.type.user_change_password: [myGroup]
    sylius.form.type.user_reset_password.validation_groups: [myGroup] # the product class also needs to be aware of the translation'a validation
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to change the password or to register, the regex is not detect. I'm sure that it works because when I change the files ChangePassword.yml, everything works. But I can't touch to the vendor's files.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Well, your regex might not work as you expect. Try `^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z]).{8,}$` or since it is PHP - `/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z]).{8,}$/`

Comment: The regex is correct, I tried it in the vendor, I tried it online, it's not that the problem. The problem is Sylius doesn't find the overwrite files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I replaced [myGroup] by [sylius].

In the tutorial it's say to custom the name, however when I did it it didn't work. So I think we have to put [sylius]